# How can I improve Nvidia graphics performance in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, flash, gnome-shell

I'm running Fedora 16 64-bit, my graphics card is an Nvidia GTS 250.

Adobe flash performance is poor compared to Windows, and GPU accelerated video decoding doesn't seem to be fully working (worked in Windows).

I'm using Google Chrome, and oddly enough, flash performs (slightly) better in Firefox.

I have the Nvidia proprietary drivers installed (version 290.10), and the VDPAU and VA libraries installed.

Also, I'm running Gnome 3, and I've noticed some serious performance degradation in Gnome Shell, since switching to the proprietary drivers from Nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

Can you dump an mp4 HD video using some YouTube downloader and check what mplayer says when playing it? (If VDPAU/VA/GLX/Xv are accelerated or not etc.)

Do you have respective 32bit XV packages also installed? Some plugins may need them (there is 64bit Flash, but you might have 32bit one installed somewhere).

Find out if your Flash player is amd64 or i386 (takes some time):

```
find / -name libflashplayer.so 2>/dev/null | xargs file
```

Comment: If you have `locate` installed, using `locate -b libflashplayer.so` would be faster than `find`.

Comment: In the age of nepomuk semantic desktop it is highly unlikely that locate is installed easily, i.e one will need to rebuild db before searching, and schedule that update.

Comment: I'll admit that `locate` (or `mlocate`) might not be installed by default on some systems (thus the reason for the conditional but I've got `mlocate` installed on all my systems) and I don't think that _nepomuk_ replaces it.

Comment: @ZaB -- I definitely have the 64-bit version of flash installed (via Adobe's YUM repository). `find / -name libflashplayer.so 2>/dev/null | xargs file
/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so:    ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so: symbolic link to `/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so' `

Comment: Also, VLC does make use of the VA API (although the video doesn't at all seem accelerated). Couldn't test with HD video (internet too slow), so I'm using a DVD. `libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0".
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib64/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva: No accelerated IMDCT transform found
va_openDriver() returns 0
[0x7fc54c086120] avcodec decoder: Using VA API version 0.32 for hardware decoding.`

Comment: Alright, I've downloaded some 1080p YouTube videos. It appears that hardware video decoding (in VLC) works better when decoding h.264 video (comparable to Windows).

Comment: Yes - h264 decoder is very compact, thus easier to program into hardware. Playing damaged xvid would take 20x more code to port to GPU.